# pip install --upgrade gives the same warning

Tags: python, pip

```
Successfully installed pip-21.0.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.1; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
```

Full trace

```
$ /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 19.7 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.6 are installed in '/home/ubuntu/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-21.0.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.1; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Despite upgrading why does it give the warning?

Comment: If you open a new shell and run `pip --version`, which version is it?

Comment: It looks like it might be related to the warning about the PATH. Does the upgrade warning disappear if you add `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin` to your PATH, then try to upgrade pip?

Comment: Adding that path to the PATH helped. But why are these scripts present in `.local` folder? I'm using usual ubuntu linux distro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have write permission to do the site-package upgrade re `site-packages is not writeable`.  You can run it with `sudo` if you wish, although for a Debian based distribution it would be more appropriate to leave package managed files alone.

```
And you are not using the local version you installed re `'/home/ubuntu/.local/bin' which is not on PATH`.

To do this,
```

export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`